# Sumar rango de valores de BD en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array, matrices

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en que el usuario pueda seleccionar un rango de meses (p.e enero-mayo) y yo seleccionar los datos disponibles en mi BD para sumarlos usando PHP. Esto debo hacerlo para cinco sedes distintas. 
El algoritmo es así:

```
+seleccione meses: enero-marzo
consolidadosede1=sede1_unidades_enero+sede1_unidades_febrero+sede1_unidades_marzo;
consolidadosede2=sede2_unidades_enero+sede2_unidades_febrero+sede2_unidades_marzo;
```

... así hasta completar las cinco sedes.
Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Agrega tu codigo por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php) suponiendo que:

```
$datos_sede1 = [
    'sede1_unidades_enero' => 100,
    'sede1_unidades_febrero' => 50,
    'sede1_unidades_marzo' => 40
];

$consolidadosede1 = array_reduce($datos_sede1, function($carry,$item){
    return $carry + $item;
});

// el valor de $consolidadosede1 es 190
```

Pero seria mas facil si lo haces en tu consulta sql

```sql
#Usando Mysql
#Esta consulta es del 1 de enero de 2010 al 1 marzo del mismo año
SELECT 
    sum(unidades) as consolodadosede1 
FROM 
    sede1 
WHERE fecha BETWEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-01';
```

Si puedes proporcionar mas información, seguramente podria ser mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Sé que he puesto poca información porque realmente no sabía cómo formular correctamente la pregunta. Sin embargo me ha servido fenomenal tu respuesta. Utilicé el segundo método que es hacer la suma desde la BD. Muchas Gracias

Comment: @RonelJimenez de nada!